# Walls not straight (obviously) how to install hardwoods?

Tags: flooring, hardwood

I’m installing Bruce hardwood flooring, I am just starting the first line against the wall and I’ve run into a problem, the spacing is 1/2” on either side, I ran my chalk line and started laying down the flooring. But the wall is pretty bowed and actually pushes out in the center by over my 1/2 “ spacing, do I try to get that 1/2” spacing in the center? Or do I just increase enough on the ends that I have the clearance to pass through the wall all the way and not have 1/2 “ in the center?

Comment: What is the wall on the other side like?

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/283619/18078 for pictures of what happens without enough space.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are talking about the wall running parallel to the long side of the boards.

You need the expansion gap, or the floor will be prone to rise off the subfloor when it expands to being trapped by the walls.

You set your edge board in position touching the wall at the outerpost point and **scribe** it to have a 1/2" gap - set a compass to 1/2", touch the wall with the leg and mark the board with the pencil or other point, dragging it all along the wall, and cut the board where marked.

If the variance in the wall is more than 1/2" you'll need to take more off the board, so set the compass wider. the goal is to have the edge of the board match the edge of the room, then set it 1/2" away from the wall. You'll generally need to do the same thing when you get to the far wall, with the adjustment of allowing for the position of the last joint so the board comes out scribed to fit and the correct width.

Answer (score 2):

You start each row with the appropriate gap prescribed by the manufacturer. Then be sure to cut the last board of the row for the same gap.

The ends should be covered with the baseboard so stagger of the boards is not an issue.

A chalk line is not helpful because most walls are not perfectly square or without bulges or dips.